# Change minutes to percentage in php

Tags: php, time, type-conversion, percentage

How to convert an hour to percentage in php format

EX:

15 mins = 25%

30 mins = 50%

60 mins = 100%

Comment: this is basic math. If you know what an hour contains in 15/60 minutes blocks, then you've found your division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple

```
(Minutes * 100) / (60 minutes)
```

Usage example:

```
$minutes = 15;
echo ($minutes * 100) / 60  . "%";
```

**Output:**
25%